# C change words beginning with lowercase to capital in text file

Tags: c, string, file, uppercase, fseek

Well I try to read a file and change every word that's beginning with a lowercase to the same word beginning with an uppercase.

This is what i got:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int zeichen;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Die Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
}
else{
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    zeichen = fgetc(fp);
    while(zeichen != EOF){
        if(zeichen == ' '){
            fseek(fp, 1L, SEEK_CUR);
            if(('a' <= zeichen) && (zeichen <= 'z')){
                zeichen = fgetc(fp);
                fputc(toupper(zeichen), fp);
            }
        }
        zeichen = fgetc(fp);
    }
    zeichen = fgetc(fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

My test.txt file does not change at all.

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Thank you for the different ways to achieve my task.

Most of them where using stuff i didn't learn yet, so i tried it by copying the characters from one file to another + making the first letter of each word an uppercase by toupper() cause it's indeed easy to use. Then deleting the old file + rename the new one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *neu;
    int zeichen;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    neu = fopen("new.txt", "w");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Die Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((zeichen = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(zeichen == ' ') {
            fputc(zeichen, neu);
            zeichen = fgetc(fp);
            zeichen = toupper(zeichen);
            fputc(zeichen, neu);
        }
        else{
            fputc(zeichen, neu);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(neu);
    remove("test.txt");
    rename("new.txt", "test.txt");
    printf("File has been changed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(zeichen == ' ')` <= you only write something different, if the character is a space. Otherwise you simply rewrite the original character. And might I introduce you to the wonderful [`toupper()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/)?

Comment: My intention was to check if the char is space, if yes, go one char forward and print it at the same place as a capital letter.

Comment: It's not obvious you need the `else { fputc(zeichen, fp);` }` clause.

Comment: Look at `if(zeichen == ' '){
            fseek(fp, 1L, SEEK_CUR);
            if(('a' <= zeichen) && (zeichen <= 'z')){`   ,  `zeichen` does not change after the first `if()`

Comment: in general this is an odd ting to do on text files (read and write), normally the file is read and a new one is written making changes as you go along (as you seem to try to do with your else clause). And then rename the new file to the old file. Also note that yr code is wrong as dhke points out, you only look at chars if they are ' '

Comment: Thank you, I used toupper() now, didn't know about this before.
I think i need else { fputc(zeichen, fp); } because with this i will write all lowercase letters.
I tried it with two files and it works, thank you for that hint.

Comment: @ManuW., if you feel that any of answers solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted to help future users finding the best solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *fp;
int zeichen;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Die Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// upper first charcter
zeichen = getc(fp);
if (zeichen != EOF) putchar(toupper(zeichen));

// scan rest of chars
while ((zeichen = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    putchar(zeichen);
    if (zeichen == ' ' && zeichen != EOF) {
        char c_upper = getc(fp);
        putchar(toupper(c_upper));
    }
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

you can use std out redirection ./main > output.txt

Answer (score 1):

Let us say a *word* begins with a letter after a space (or white-space) or at file beginning.

Look for the pattern `<space><lowercase>`

Seeking relative to `SEEK_CUR` should be avoided for text files.

```
bool previous_space = true;
long offset = ftell(fp);  // remember where we are
while(offset != -1 && (zeichen = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  if (previous_space && islower(zeichen)) {
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET); 
    fputc(toupper(zeichen), fp);
  }
  previous_space = isspace(zeichen);
  offset = ftell(fp);
}
```

---

OP's code had trouble as `fseek()` was not needed and `('a' <= zeichen) && (zeichen <= 'z')` is always false (in ASCII) as `' '` is not between `'a'` and `'z'`.

```
    if(zeichen == ' '){
        fseek(fp, 1L, SEEK_CUR);
        if(('a' <= zeichen) && (zeichen <= 'z')){
            zeichen = fgetc(fp);
            fputc(toupper(zeichen), fp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trivia: If `ch` is a  letter `A-Z,a-z`, `ch ^= 'A' ^ 'a';` will change the case in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and most unicorn encodings. which have a consistent bit difference between the case of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that focusing on words you can achieve more secure results, if your file contains only space separated words, you can rely on first letter after space character.

You tried to use the [`fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html) which is not not bad at all but I would use it differently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    int zeichen;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Die Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((zeichen = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(zeichen == ' ') {
            zeichen = fgetc(fp);
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc(toupper(zeichen), fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Stepping back after reading the first letter next to a space is important, because [`fgetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html) (and [`fputc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputc.html) too) autmatically step the cursor forward after reading. So, to rewrite the current letter to its upper case counterpart, you have to step back the cursor.

The shortcomings of my example are that it won't change the first letter of the first word in a file and it's important to the file should not end with a space but with a word.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of an overkill, let alone some things I am not that smart to understand (for example why you are checking for the space character, why the condition of checking for a lowercase is `('a' <= zeichen) && (zeichen <= 'z')` and not `'a' >= ...`). Moreover the non-universal language makes it tough for me. Some of them are already explained in the comments, so I will try to explain what I would do.

I wouldn't try to `fseek()` all the time, I would read the file once and then write the data once again. Here is my algorithm:

1. Read file line by line.
2. Store every word in a 2D array.
3. Check if a word starts with a lowercase, and if so swap that
   lowercase letter with an uppercase one.
4. Now the array holds all the data I need to write to the file.
5. Set the file pointer to the start of the file.
6. Iterate over the stored words in the array and write them to file.

---

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 5   // max number of words to be read
#define LEN 10  // max lenght of a word allowed

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    char buffer[MAX][LEN]; // read up to 5 words, of at most 10 characters
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int count = 0;
    while(count < MAX && fgets(buffer[count], LEN, fp)) {
        if(buffer[count][strlen(buffer[count]) - 1] == '\n') buffer[count][strl$
        //printf("%s\n", buffer[count]);
        if(islower(buffer[count][0]))
            buffer[count][0] = (char)toupper(buffer[count][0]);
        //printf("%s\n", buffer[count]);
        count++;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", buffer[i]);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

which will overwrite the contents of this file:

```
Manu
Samaras
small
```

to this:

```
Manu
Samaras
Small
```

Comment: Will not `fgets(buffer[count], LEN, fp)` split words like "hijk" in "abcd efg hijk\n"`.

Comment: But OP said that the file contains words @chux. Except if the case is that the file contains text and he means every single word in general. In that case yes, and your answer should be followed (I am out of votes). :/